# How can I charge my customer's credit cards, then deposit funds in my bank account using bitcoin?

Tags: transactions, payment, payment-processors

I would appreciate if anyone could please help me as I didn't have any experiences with Bitcoin yet.

I would like to charge my clients' credit cards. The funds would come to my USA bank account (should not matter if its personal or business). Is this possible? So instead of using some kind of 'ewallet,' funds would be instantly transferred/sent to my USA bank account FROM clients' credit cards. Then, I enter the cards details. Is this possible?

Comment: GymAddict, I have edited your question down to something more likely to be answered.

Comment: Oh, seeing GymAddict's response below shows this question is asking simply about standard credit/debit payment card merchant processor account.

Comment: @GymAddict, look up SquareUp.com

Answer (score 1):

[BitPay](https://bitpay.com/) allows you to accept payments in bitcoins receiving any combination of hard currency and bitcoins (you can chose 100% hard currency if you want).

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but honestly your post is so confused it's hard to tell: if this is not what you are looking for, please try to be more clear (no offence intended, of course).

Comment: I have no idea what do you mean with the term 'bitcoins'. Never seen that word. My 3 questions aren't consufing. I asked very clearly and hopefully I could get answers.

Comment: You asked a question on a bitcoin forum, so people have assumed you were discussing bitcoin payments.

Answer (score 0):

No payment processors offer this, currently.

If you are in the U.S., you could have the direct deposit/ACH transfer that your VISA/Mastercard merchant processor sends your funds to be one that you have linked to with Dwolla or Coinbase, and then use those funds drawn right back out to buy bitcoins.

There is a [thread in the BitcoinTalk forum](http://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=113336.msg1224161#msg1224161) with more discussion on this topic.